# Passin args to laravel eloquent api resources constructor

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

How I can pass args to Laravel Eloquent API Resources constructor and get it to conditional data returning on response?

**What I tried:**

Controller

```
$user = User::find(1);
return new UserResource($user, $shortData = true);
```

API Resource:

```
public function toArray($request, $shortData)
{
    if($short) {
        return $shortData;
    } else {
        return $fullData;
    }
}
```

Comment: *What I tried:* What was error/result?

Comment: @Tpojka No error result. This code only not worked for me. Wher set value of `$shortData` true or false in both case return full data

Answer (score 8):

You have to do something like this :

- Add the conditional data in your constructor (like you did). This conditional data can be null :

```
$user = User::find(1);
return new UserResource($user, $conditionalData);
```

- Then in your UserResource, add the conditional data as a private attribute and add it to your constructor like this (it works as well with PHP default argument value...) :

```
private $conditionalData;

    public function __construct(User $resource, ?string $conditionalData)
    {
        parent::__construct($resource);
        $this->conditionalData = $conditionalData;
    }
```

- Last thing you have to do is to use Laravel Conditional Attribute system (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes). The **when** method allows you to expressively define your resources without resorting to conditional statements when building the array.

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data_1' => $this->data1,
            'data_2' => $this->data2,
            'conditional_data' => $this->when(!is_null($this->conditionalData), $this->$conditionalData)
        ];
    }
```

Your conditional data will be present in your response only if the attribute is not null.